# Masking body parts underneath clothes and armor?

Tags: unity, shape-keys, masking

I have game character with armor, and I need to avoid parts of the body clipping through the armor.

I tried using shape keys to shrink body parts under clothing, but it seems like it would be a lot easier to just hide the majority of the body that is underneath.

What would be the best way to go about this? I also need to be able to export the resulting mesh to Unity.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is with a "Mask Modifier", simply create a vertex group and add weight to the vertices you want to keep visible. then on your object's modifiers, add the one named "Mask" and set the vertex group box to whatever name you called the one you just added the weight to, and voila! its now masked
:D!!!

Step 1:
Add vertex group and weight paint the parts you want to be visible

[image]

Step 2: Add "Mask" modifier and select the vertex group you just created, I named mine "Mask"

[image]

Step 3: Confirm that it was done properly (I changed the armor piece visibility from textured to wireframe to demonstrate this)

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps n.n!

Comment: Yes very much so! Now i need to figure out a way to code this into unity when the piece of clothing is equipped! Thank you!